# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when accessing URL

Tags: ios, swift

I am asking Google for the distance between two coordinates TWICE. When I need to set the distance value to the UILabel, I do this:

```
func getDistancia(origenLat:Double, origenLon:Double, destinoLat:Double, destinoLon:Double){
    var url:String = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origenLat),\(origenLon)&destination=\(destinoLat),\(destinoLon)&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving"
    startConnection(url)   
}

func startConnection(url:String){
    let urlPath: String = url
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string:url)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError

    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary //The error pops here
    var routes: NSArray=jsonResult.valueForKey("routes") as! NSArray
    var routesDic:NSDictionary=routes[0] as! NSDictionary
    var legs:NSArray=routesDic.valueForKey("legs") as! NSArray
    var distanceDic:NSDictionary=legs[0] as! NSDictionary
    //var valor:String=distanceDic.valueForKey("text") as! String
    var finalDistanceDic:NSDictionary=distanceDic.valueForKey("distance") as! NSDictionary
    var valor:String=finalDistanceDic.valueForKey("text") as! String
    ofiDistanciaLabel.text=valor

}
```

This works ok the first time. Later, in a MapKit instance, when the user taps in any part of the map, I detect if there is any town close to where the user tapped, and calculate the distance from the new point. I update the origin and destination points (called origen and destino in my code) and call getDistancia method again. I do it this way:

```
map.removeAnnotations(self.map.annotations)
        var latSeleccionado=pueblosSeleccionados[0].latitud
        var lonSeleccionado=pueblosSeleccionados[0].longitud
        var ofiId=pueblosSeleccionados[0].idOficina
        var ofiQuery="select * from oficinas where id=\(ofiId!)"
        badajozDB?.open()
        let resultOficina2:FMResultSet?=badajozDB?.executeQuery(ofiQuery, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        var oficina=Oficina()
        if(resultOficina2?.next()==true){

            oficina.municipio=resultOficina2?.stringForColumn("localidad")
            oficina.direccion=resultOficina2?.stringForColumn("direccion")
            oficina.latitud=resultOficina2?.doubleForColumn("latitud")
            oficina.longitud=resultOficina2?.doubleForColumn("longitud")
            oficina.telefono=resultOficina2?.stringForColumn("telefono")
            oficina.fax=resultOficina2?.stringForColumn("fax")
            oficina.email=resultOficina2?.stringForColumn("correo")

        }
        origen?.latitud=latSeleccionado
        origen?.longitud=lonSeleccionado
        destino?.latitud=oficina.latitud
        destino?.longitud=oficina.longitud
        ofiMunicipioLabel.text=oficina.municipio
        ofiDireccionLabel.text=oficina.direccion
        ofiPhoneLabel.text=oficina.telefono
        ofiFaxLabel.text=oficina.fax
        ofiEmailLabel.text=oficina.email
        getDistancia(origen!.latitud!, origenLon: origen!.longitud!, destinoLat: destino!.latitud!, destinoLon: destino!.longitud!)
        zoomToFit()
        badajozDB?.close()
```

But the second time, I receive "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" error, and I don't know why it happens. The new coordinates are ok, the URL is ok, SQL sentence is formed correctly...but I receive this error.

Anyone knows why could this happen?

Thank you.

EDIT:
zoomToFit() method:

```
func zoomToFit() {
    var allLocations:[CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: origen!.latitud!, longitude: origen!.longitud!),
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destino!.latitud!, longitude: destino!.longitud!)
    ]

    var poly:MKPolygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: &allLocations, count: allLocations.count)

    self.map.setVisibleMapRect(poly.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsetsMake(40.0, 40.0, 40.0, 40.0), animated: false)
    var locationOrigen = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: origen!.latitud!,
        longitude: origen!.longitud!
    )

    var locationDestino=CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: destino!.latitud!, longitude: destino!.longitud!)
    var annotationDestino=MKPointAnnotation()
    var annotationOrigen = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotationOrigen.coordinate = locationOrigen
    annotationDestino.coordinate=locationDestino

    map.addAnnotation(annotationOrigen)
    map.addAnnotation(annotationDestino)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, despite the super-descriptive and accurate error message.

In case someone has the same problem in the future:

The problem was, the variable data is not overwritten, the new data is appended new values.

So, I create a new NSMutableData object every time the program enters the method connection:

```
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){

    self.data=NSMutableData()

    self.data!.appendData(data)
    println("Data: \(self.data)")
}
```

And this way works ok.